# How to refresh Fragment inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have searched a lot but can't find solution which will be suitable for my code.
Actually i have tablayout in fragment and for tablayout i am using viewpager. There are 3 fragments inside viewpager. There is one spinner in my activity i want when user selects item from spinner then viewpager fragments data should be changed according to selected value but it is not updating the data.

Can anyone help to solve it. I want viewpager fragment should be refreshed whenever spinner's selected value will be changed.

My MainActivity code:

```
binding.bottmNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.location:
                    final AlertDialog.Builder mbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
                    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
                    Button okbutton = v.findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
                    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HomeActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_list));
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    mbuilder.setView(v);
                    final AlertDialog dialog = mbuilder.create();


                   okbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                           Log.e("Dialog123", "onClick: Positive" );


                           SharedPreferences prfs;
                           prfs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(HomeActivity.this);
                           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prfs.edit();
                           editor.putString("savedvalue", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                           editor.commit();
                           String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                           newsModels = new ArrayList<>();

                           if(text.equals("INDIA")) {
                               newsModels.clear();
                               TypedArray indianewslogo = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.indianews);
                               String[] indianewsname = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.indianewsnames);
                               String[] indianewsurl = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.indiahref);
                               for(int i =0; i<indianewslogo.length(); i++) {
                                   //SendModel sendModel = new SendModel(indianewslogo.getResourceId(i,0),indianewsname[i]);
                                   newsModels.add(new NewsModel(indianewslogo.getResourceId(i,0),indianewsname[i], indianewsurl[i]));
                               }
                               Singleton.getConstant().addNewsModel(newsModels);
                               TypedArray indiashopimg = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.indiashopimg);
                               String [] indishopname = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.indiashopname);
                               String[] indiashopurl = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.indiashopurl);
                               sendModels = new ArrayList<>();
                               for(int j =0; j<indiashopimg.length(); j++){
                                   SendModel sendModel = new SendModel(indiashopimg.getResourceId(j,0), indishopname[j], indiashopurl[j]);
                                   sendModels.add(sendModel);
                               }
                               SendSingleton.getConstant().addNewsModel(sendModels);

                               FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                               fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, homeFragment);
                               fragmentTransaction.commit();
                               binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.location).setTitle("India");
                               binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.home1).setChecked(true);

                               dialog.dismiss();
                           }else if(text.equals("USA")){
                               newsModels.clear();
                               TypedArray indianewslogo = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.usnews);
                               String[] indianewsname = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.usnewsname);
                               String[] indianewsurl = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.usurl);
                               for(int i =0; i<indianewslogo.length(); i++) {

                                   newsModels.add(new NewsModel(indianewslogo.getResourceId(i,0),indianewsname[i], indianewsurl[i]));
                               }
                               Singleton.getConstant().addNewsModel(newsModels);

                               Singleton.getConstant().addNewsModel(newsModels);
                               TypedArray indiashopimg = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.usashopimg);
                               String [] indishopname = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.usashopname);
                               String[] indiashopurl = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.usashopurl);
                               sendModels = new ArrayList<>();
                               for(int j =0; j<indiashopimg.length(); j++){
                                   SendModel sendModel = new SendModel(indiashopimg.getResourceId(j,0), indishopname[j], indiashopurl[j]);
                                   sendModels.add(sendModel);
                               }
                               SendSingleton.getConstant().addNewsModel(sendModels);

                               FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                               fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, homeFragment);
                               fragmentTransaction.commit();

                               binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.location).setTitle("USA");
                               binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.home1).setChecked(true);
                               dialog.dismiss();

                           }
```

HomeFragment(Where viewpager is placed):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final FragmentHomeBinding homeBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    sendModels = new ArrayList<>();

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), homeBinding.tablayout.getTabCount());
    homeBinding.viewpager1.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    homeBinding.tablayout.setupWithViewPager(homeBinding.viewpager1);
    homeBinding.viewpager1.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    homeBinding.tablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            homeBinding.viewpager1.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }@Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }@Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
    homeBinding.viewpager1.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(homeBinding.tablayout));
```

NewsFragment(Where i want to show the data):

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final FragmentNewsBinding binding= DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_news, container,  false);
    View view = binding.getRoot();

    newsModels = new ArrayList<>();
    newsModels =Singleton.getConstant().getNewsModel();

    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager =new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 4);
    binding.recylerview.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    binding.recylerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(newsModels, getContext());
    binding.recylerview.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter Code:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private Map<Integer, String> mfragmenttags;
private FragmentManager mfragmentManager;
private String[]  tabtitles= new String[]{"News", "Shopping", "Social"};
private int numofTabs;

public PagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int numofTabs) {
    super(fm);
    mfragmentManager = fm;
    this.numofTabs = numofTabs;
    mfragmenttags = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabtitles[position];
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new NewsFragment();
        case 1:
            return new ShoppingFragment();
        case 2:
            return new SocialFragment();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    if(obj instanceof Fragment ){
        Fragment f = (Fragment)obj;
        String tag = f.getTag();
        mfragmenttags.put(position, tag);

    }
    return obj;
}
public Fragment getFragment(int position){
    String tag = mfragmenttags.get(position);
    if(tag == null){
        return null;
    }
    return mfragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numofTabs;
}
```

}

Comment: Where is your spinner? Activity or fragment?

Comment: Share your activity code

Comment: spinner is on actiivty

Comment: i have updated my whole code. please check.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all logic code fetch data (or load data) in both place are onCreated and onNewIntent

- onCreated is called in first time
- onNewIntent is called when u show again that fragment

Hope this help!

Comment: You just need place all logic code you reload data in both onCreated and onNewIntent. I explained above. Its work for me.

Comment: Actually data is coming in recyclerview but when i click on spinner and selecting any item then its not updating with new data. why so?

Comment: i want viewpager fragment should refresh after every selection from spinner.

Comment: Everytime u select item in spinner. Such as u select a fragment. So if that fragment is created. It will call onNewIntent. Else it will call onCreated. So you just need update data on both functions. Its right?

Answer (score 0):

Create public methods `refresh()` inside your fragments that you want to refresh. Add the below code to call `refresh()` inside your `setOnItemSelectedListener` of the spinner

```
for (Fragment fragment : getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
     if (fragment instanceof NewsFragment) {
         ((NewsFragment) fragment).refresh(); //add refresh method in fragment
     }

}
```

Comment: and what should i write in refresh() method??

Comment: The logic you want that will change the data inside that fragment

Comment: if it is recyclerview code i want to write in fragment then what should refresh() method return.?

Comment: Do binding.notifyDataSetChanged(); or create and set adapter again

Comment: i tried ur code but it did not help me...data is not refreshing on every item of spinner.